# How to change html in a animation that is animate by scroll?

Tags: javascript, html, css

```
<div class="avator">
    <div class="content"></div>
</div>
```

with my scroll to the bottom it will change the div to:

```
<div class="avator">
   <img src="/image/avator.png" />
</div>
```

with the scroll the alpha changes. and if I stop scroll the change will stop.
how to to it?

Comment: You mean that when you scroll down the page the image will slowly appear?

Comment: @ciekals11 yes.that is. an image or divs.

Answer (score 0):

let's say we have a div like this in your example

```
<div class="avator">
   <img src="/image/avator.png" />
</div>
```

then let's add to `.avator img` a property `opacity: 0;`
css

```
.avator img { opacity: 0; }
```

now let's calculate opacity value based on % of page scrolled and asign it to `.avator img` (I prefer using jQuery so here is an example in jQuery)

```js
$(window).on('scroll', function(){
  let windowScroll = $(window).scrollTop();
  let docHeight = $(document).height();
  let windowHeight = $(window).height();

  let scrollFromTop = (windowScroll / (docHeight - windowHeight))

  $('.avator img').css({
    'opacity': scrollFromTop
  })
})
```

this will updated opacity of `.avator img` every time user will use scroll
Ofc you can replace `img` with `div` and make div appear like that